# Current time - last tim (java)

Tags: java, android, date

Sorry for my English. I have current time `2015-07-31 12:19:55` and last time `2015-07-31 13:38:20` and i don't know how to get date difference. Example:

```
2015-07-31 12:19:55 - 2015-07-31 13:38:20 = date what i need
```

My simple code:

```
private Date date = new Date();
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private String currectDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    private String lastLoginDate = "2015-07-31 12:19:55";
```

Comment: need date difference?

Comment: @Satya thanks for answer, yes need date difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    java.text.DateFormat outputFormat1 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
    Date d1 = outputFormat1.parse("2015-07-31 12:19:55");//start date
    Date d2 = outputFormat1.parse("2015-07-31 13:38:20");//end date
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;//in terms of hours
    long diffmin = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;//in mimutes
    long diffsec = diff / (1000) % 60;//in seconds
    String rtime=diffHours+"h:"+diffmin+"m:"+diffsec+"s";
    System.out.println(rtime);//1h:18m:25s
```

in terms of days?

```
  long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);//in terms of days
```

Use [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)

```
Period period = new Period(d1, d2);
System.out.print(period.getYears() + " years, ");
System.out.print(period.getMonths() + " months, ");
```